Nginx reverse proxy to kubernetes resource api not working for watch-operations
I have a Minikube cluster on my server. I want to expose the Kubernetes resource API. Which is not directly possible, because the Minikube IP is 192.168.49.2 which is only accessible on the server. Therefore I use nginx to serve it on k8s.mydomain.com.
server {
    server_name k8s.mydomain.com;
    auth_basic "Administrator’s Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.49.2:8443;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /home/admin/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location "/*" {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.49.2:8443;
        proxy_ssl_certificate /home/admin/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/k8s.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/k8s.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = k8s.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name k8s.mydomain.com;


    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

This Nginx config works for most things like e.g. k get pods or k apply -f deployment.yaml. (on the server and on another device)
But for things which are watching it doesn't work.
For example k logs -f podname or k get -w pods. To be more specific. If I execute k logs -f podname on another device it shows the past logs (just like without the -f), but it doesn't show new logs (which are for sure generated).
How should my nginx config look like to make the watch-operations possible on other devices which are calling k8s.mydomain.com.
I could use commands to serve the kube-api to an local, from outside accessible, port, but I want an automated way which doesn't require some commands (even after restart).
My kube-config looks like this. This works currently for the non-watch-operation. Can you please share also the kube-config if somethings needs to be changed there.
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Thu, 22 Jun 2023 19:21:36 CEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.30.1
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://k8s.mydomain.com
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Thu, 22 Jun 2023 19:21:36 CEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.30.1
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    password: ${KUBE_PWD}
    username: minikube


Be aware that nginx has poor support for http2. Consider to use another proxy if you want to proxy http2 features.

use those watch-operations http2 features? Is there still a way to use nginx for these operations, because I have many other domains also using nginx on this server (port 80 and 443 can either be used by nginx or another tool but not both).

Try configuring Nginx to handle WebSocket connections with the help of this  Document : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-websocket#:~:text=NGINX supports WebSocket by allowing,headers must be set explicitly.&text=Once this is done%2C NGINX,this as a WebSocket connection.
